# Update configuration file with Ant

Tags: javascript, web-applications, ant, configuration

I'm not looking for a full working solution for my question, but for a recommendation on how to achieve something.

I have a web application with a javascript file which contains some constants and default values.

I'm using ant to build and package the application, so I have 2 targets, one for development and another one for production. The thing is, in my configuration file some constants have a default value for production but another one in development.

Right now, if I'm developing and I want to prepare a delivery for production I have to:
  - manually edit configuration file to set right values (comment some lines and uncomment some others)
  - run ant production target

I'd like to automate this, so when I run my ant target for production, the correct default values are used in my configuration javascript file. Can ant achieve this (search for some lines in a javascript file and edit that file)? is this a bad practice? any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a suggestion, I would have two configuration files -dev and -prod and then use ant to move the right file to the build dir, renaming it if needed

- You can write to a file using the echo task

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html

- Replace Task is a directory based task for replacing the occurrence of a given string with another string in selected file.

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html

Comment: yep, that's much more clever that what I was trying to do, thanks!